# Why is Pasporta Servo Not Allowing Me to Register?

Tags: pasporta-servo

I enter my username, matching passwords, and email address, and click register, but it returns me to the same screen, with the password fields deleted. I have not received any registration email.

Comment: I'm not sure this question fits within the scope of Esperanto Language StackExchange.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about the Esperanto language, rather it is a technical problem the person is having.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

developer here.
First, it’s clear that there is a User Experience issue, as you don’t receive any feedback after a not successful form sending.

Nevertheless, if your password are matching, it boils down to this issue: either your username or email is already taken. This might mean you already registered before.

Please contact us per: saluton *[ĉe]* pasportaservo·org

Comment: I just tried it again and it worked. It looks like the issue has been fixed!